# Cannot copy password to remote console using mstsc.exe

Tags: remote-desktop, mstsc

I am running Windows Vista Business Edition and I am trying to connect to Windows Server 2003 Web Edition using Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe). When the remote computer asks for the user name and password the clipboard doesn't work (in both directions). After logging in the clipboard works fine. Since we are using long passwords this is really annoying.

Do you have any idea how I may tweak the settings to allow copying user name and password to remote console during logging in process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want using RDP. Clipboard support is handled through a side channel in the RDP stream and requires support from the remote end. In Microsoft's RDP implementation, that support is provided by the usermode rdpclip.exe process, which is started by winlogon.exe - obviously only once you're already logged in. splattne's answer is the only way to do it.

You could try to find (or write :D) an alternative RDP client which does what you want, but AFAIK there is none available at the moment.

Comment: That's weird. I would swear that it worked at WinXP. I do some experiments and it looks like you are clearly right. I was clearly confused. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to do that. A workaround is to let Remote Desktop Connection save your password. Flag that checkbox in "Options."

As alternative you could use [Royal TS](http://www.code4ward.net/main/RoyalTS/Overview.aspx). It's free until [version 1.5.1](http://www.code4ward.net/main/RoyalTS/Download/StatisticandpreviousVersions.aspx).

Comment: Yes I know but I am pretty sure that it violate most security policies.

Comment: Yes, but copying the password from ... is better? ;-)

Comment: I am using KeePass (see http://keepass.info/). I think/hope it's quite secure way of storing passwords.

Comment: Royal TS also allows to store the document and/or password encrypted. Depending on the pass phrase it is as safe as keepass.